# Is there a way to return a single Claim value using a key or identifier in a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity

I am accessing all my claims by looping through all of them using a for each statement. I want to be getting a single value using the identifier like below where the **name** is the identifier.

```
User.Claims.Type[name]
```

Currently i am accessing my claims like this and all the values are being returned

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    foreach(var claim in User.Claims)
    {
        @claim.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: a linq expression perhaps?

Comment: This is all done in the view. Let me edit the question

Comment: Claims identity has the FindFirst method.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - yes quite right - even easier!